# final in constructor and property

Tags: java

I have a final property and a constructor:

```
public abstract class AbstractTest<T> {

    protected final T test;

    // no need for final, as property is already declared as final?
    protected AbstractTest(final T test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

}
```

Should I put `final` to both, property and constructor or is this the same as leaving `final` from constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protected AbstractTest(final T test) {
    this.test = test;
}
```

Marking a function parameter `final` prevents you from modifying the variable inside the function. It doesn't affect callers at all, nor does it affect any other part of the class. Outside code won't care one way or the other; it's only relevant inside the function implementation.

```
protected AbstractTest(final T test) {
    this.test = test;
    test = null;       // Illegal if the parameter is final, legal otherwise.
}
```

It's up to you if you want to mark parameters final or not.

If you're wondering whether `this.test` being final means the `test` parameter should also be final: **no**. One has no bearing on the other. You could mark both variables final, neither final, or one final and not the other.

If you're still unsure what to do, my advice is: don't mark parameters final. It's extra typing with almost zero benefit.

Answer (score 1):

'final' is a property of the variable, not the referenced object.

After this:

```
protected AbstractTest(final T test) {
    this.test = test;
}
```

you can still modify the object referenced by `this.test`:

```
this.test.something = 42;
```

(assuming appropriate access; but declaring `this.test` as `final T test` does not stop you).

The 'final' applied to your constructor argument only prevents you from assigning to the constructor argument 'test'.  Since you don't want to do this anyway, it makes no difference.  And even if you did assign to 'test', as in perhaps:

```
   this.test = test;
   test = null;
```

it would make no difference that the caller could see; you're changing your local copy of the argument variable, not the object it points to.

So, 'final' there is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different variables: The field and the parameter.

In both cases, `final` means that the variable cannot be changed after initial assignment.

Since the parameter is assigned when the method / constructor is called, it means that it can never be changed. Which is generally a good thing, because changing the value of a parameter can be confusing.

Anyway, the 2 variables are their own, so the 2 `final` modifiers are entirely independent, so you should leave them both.

Personally, I never put `final` on a parameter. Instead, I turn on the compiler warning if I attempt to change the value. That way I don't have superfluous keywords, but that's just my coding style. Specifying `final` means that compiler would always *fail* the compilation, instead of only warning about it, and that cannot be missed or suppressed by mistake, so your choice on that one.

Answer (score 0):

the use of final in a variable in java means it would be constant after it receive a value.

When you declaring the variable as constant you don't need to put final any time it appears like in

```
protected AbstractTest(final T test)
```

just put

```
protected AbstractTest(T test)
```